Can’t find SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h with cmake
Building on a Mac under CMake, I am trying to use SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h . The compiler can't find it, although it finds SDL2/SDL.h without difficulty. I installed SDL2 using homebrew.  I pursued the instructions given in this answer, but it’s not finding. I have tried both forms:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>                  // This works
#include <SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>   // This doesn't work
#include <SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>        // This doesn't work either

Here's CMakeLists.txt.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(my-project)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} . Library APClass Library/jpeg)

add_library(Drawbox STATIC)

add_subdirectory(Library)
add_subdirectory(Tools)
add_subdirectory(APClass)

target_compile_features(Drawbox PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_options(Drawbox PRIVATE -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-writable-strings)

The file I'm trying to compile is SDL/Drawbox.SDL.cpp  i.e. in the subdirectory SDL under the Library directory. Here's CMakeLists.txt for the Library subdirectory:
target_sources(Drawbox
    PRIVATE
# ...skipping files to shorten this question’s text...
        PVector.cpp Point.cpp Rect.cpp SpaceCalc.cpp Timer.cpp
        SDL/Drawbox.SDL.cpp  SDL/Keyboard.SDL.cpp
)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

The final line was my effort to help this problem, and it neither shows an error (which might have indicated that SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS was undefined in context) nor fixes the problem.
% ll /opt/local/include/SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    11K Dec 19  2020 /opt/local/include/SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h
% ll /opt/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7.9K Sep  1  2023 /opt/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h

Searching for files, I find that lying around on my desktop I have a probably old copy of SDL2.framework, which contains SDL.h but not SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h. But that's not considered a standard install location and should not be found by CMake, right?

Add message( STATUS SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS=${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ) to your CMakeLists.txt and type cmake . in the build folder to see what value SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS contains. I expect its empty and the #include <SDL2/SDL.h> works because it found that file in the system headers in /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h or similar.

"I installed SDL2 using homebrew."  But did you install sdl2_gfx?

Thanks, @drescherjm, that's exactly what I needed to know. But the results were not as you expected. They are:
SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include/SDL2 .
This is not a real directory. That path is good through /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.30.3/include and thereafter it is hallucinating! That directory contains a subdirectory SDL2 which does NOT contain SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h .
How might I guide CMake to do better? Or work around this apparent bug?

Thanks, @genpfault, that needed to be done. But perhaps you can address the deeper question: what is the algorithm for finding out that things like that need to be done? When one package doesn't contain everything that it apparently should contain, but has friends and relations?

Unfortunately, although sdl2_gfx clearly needed to be installed, installing it did not fix this problem!

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html I believe adding  NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH  to your find_package will get it to ignore the system location. Then specifying PATHS can direct find_package to use the path you want.
